# Go version Stripe Checkout tutorial can't be compiled, undefined: session

Tags: go, go-gin, stripe-payments

I'm trying a [Stripe Checkout tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment) with golang and gin. But the following code can't be build due to the error as **undefined: session**.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    stripe "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71"
)

func main(){
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/buy/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
        stripe.Key = "sk_test_MyKey............"

        params := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{
            PaymentMethodTypes: stripe.StringSlice([]string{
                    "card",
                    "ideal",
            }),
            LineItems: []*stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
                    &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemParams{
                            PriceData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataParams{
                                Currency: stripe.String("stripe.String(stripe.CurrencyEUR)"),
                                ProductData: &stripe.CheckoutSessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataParams{
                                    Name: stripe.String("T-shirt"),
                                },
                                UnitAmount: stripe.Int64(2000),
                            },
                            Quantity: stripe.Int64(1),
                    },
            },
            Mode: stripe.String("payment"),
            SuccessURL: stripe.String("https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"),
            CancelURL: stripe.String("https://example.com/cancel"),
        }
        s, err := session.New(params)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        } else {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
                "SessionID": s.id,
            })  
        }
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Does anyone knows why **session** is undefined? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the package containing [session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions): [Go package docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/stripe/stripe-go/checkout/session)

```
import "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71/checkout/session"
```

They do link to it from the [Create a Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#create-checkout-session) section, but they forgot the include in the code snippets.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for so your quick reply! But I'm facing type error:


cannot use params (type *"github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71".CheckoutSessionParams) as type *"github.com/stripe/stripe-go".CheckoutSessionParams in argument to session.New

Comment: Fixed, I forgot about the version number.